# Optimize mysql multiple left joins

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a query like this:

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(c.cantitate) AS num,
  p.id             AS pid,
  p.titlu          AS titlu,
  p.alias          AS alias,
  p.gramaj         AS gramaj,
  p.prettotal      AS prettotal,
  p.pretunitar     AS pretunitar,
  p.pretredus      AS pretredus,
  p.stoc           AS stoc,
  p.cant_variabila AS cant_variabila,
  p.nou            AS nou,
  p.congelat       AS congelat,
  p.cod            AS cod,
  p.poza           AS poza,
  cc.seo           AS seo
FROM produse p
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT  produs, cantitate, COS FROM comenzi) c ON p.id = c.produs
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT STATUS, id FROM cosuri) cs ON c.cos = cs.id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, seo FROM categorii) cc ON p.categorie = cc.id
WHERE cs.status = 'closed' AND p.vizibil = '1'
GROUP BY pid
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 0, 14
```

The query is working, but Duration for 1 query: 2.922 sec.
How can I improve the query  ?

The keys are as following :

comenzi: cos, produs as unique key

cosuri: id as unique key

produse: titlu, categorie, alias as key

Comment: I'm sorry, but we'll need more details, such as `EXPLAIN` output and the schemas/indexes involved. As it stands now, the question is - using a car analogy - similar to "here's a picture of my car, why won't it start?".

Comment: Lose the subqueries and join onto the tables, save MySQL from copying the whole table into a temp table. MySQL is smart enough to only use parts of a table it needs, there's no need to use subqueries to try and reduce the number of rows, let the database engine handle that.

Comment: With subquery Duration for 1 query: 3.047 sec and Duration for 1 query: 3.969 sec without subquery

Answer (score 4):

As you have lot many `sub-queries`, the time will spent on the full data read. If you apply join directly on the table instead of `sub query` it will boost the performance.

Try it after removing all subqueries. Like:

```
SELECT
  SUM(c.cantitate) AS num,
  p.id             AS pid,
  p.titlu          AS titlu,
  p.alias          AS alias,
  p.gramaj         AS gramaj,
  p.prettotal      AS prettotal,
  p.pretunitar     AS pretunitar,
  p.pretredus      AS pretredus,
  p.stoc           AS stoc,
  p.cant_variabila AS cant_variabila,
  p.nou            AS nou,
  p.congelat       AS congelat,
  p.cod            AS cod,
  p.poza           AS poza,
  cc.seo           AS seo
FROM produse p
  LEFT JOIN comenzi c
    ON p.id = c.produs
  LEFT JOIN cosuri cs
    ON c.cos = cs.id
  LEFT JOIN categorii cc
    ON p.categorie = cc.id
WHERE cs.status = 'closed'
    AND p.vizibil = '1'
GROUP BY pid
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 0, 14
```

You should have following indexes as well:

```
+---------+------------+
|  TABLE  |   COLUMN   |
+---------+------------+
| produse | categorie  |
| produse | vizibil    |
| comenzi | produs     |
| comenzi | cos        |
| cosuri  | status     |
+---------+------------+
```

Assuming that `id` column table is `PK` in all tables otherwise `index` is required for these columns as well.

Comment: @speedy: Do an EXPLAIN to make sure the keys you have are actually used.

Comment: with #Ambrish indexes Duration for 1 query: 2.813 sec on localhost

Comment: Do have index on `cosuri`.`status`. If not then create and test the query again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:It will take less time

```
SELECT
  SUM(c.cantitate) AS num,
  p.id             AS pid,
  p.titlu          AS titlu,
  p.alias          AS alias,
  p.gramaj         AS gramaj,
  p.prettotal      AS prettotal,
  p.pretunitar     AS pretunitar,
  p.pretredus      AS pretredus,
  p.stoc           AS stoc,
  p.cant_variabila AS cant_variabila,
  p.nou            AS nou,
  p.congelat       AS congelat,
  p.cod            AS cod,
  p.poza           AS poza,
  cc.seo           AS seo
FROM produse p
  LEFT JOIN comenzi c ON p.id = c.produs
  LEFT JOIN cosuri cs ON c.cos = cs.id
  LEFT JOIN categorii cc ON p.categorie = cc.id
WHERE cs.status = 'closed' AND p.vizibil = '1'
GROUP BY pid
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 0, 14
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be fast

```
SELECT
  SUM(c.cantitate) AS num,
  p.id             AS pid,
  p.titlu          AS titlu,
  p.alias          AS alias,
  p.gramaj         AS gramaj,
  p.prettotal      AS prettotal,
  p.pretunitar     AS pretunitar,
  p.pretredus      AS pretredus,
  p.stoc           AS stoc,
  p.cant_variabila AS cant_variabila,
  p.nou            AS nou,
  p.congelat       AS congelat,
  p.cod            AS cod,
  p.poza           AS poza,
  cc.seo           AS seo
FROM produse p
  LEFT JOIN comenzi c ON p.id = c.produs
  LEFT JOIN cosuri cs ON c.cos = cs.id
  LEFT JOIN categorii cc ON p.categorie = cc.id
WHERE cs.status = 'closed' AND p.vizibil = '1'
GROUP BY pid
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 0, 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the subqueries. There won't help you. Test this at tell us how much it takes.

```
SELECT
  SUM(c.cantitate) AS num,
  p.id             AS pid,
  p.titlu          AS titlu,
  p.alias          AS alias,
  p.gramaj         AS gramaj,
  p.prettotal      AS prettotal,
  p.pretunitar     AS pretunitar,
  p.pretredus      AS pretredus,
  p.stoc           AS stoc,
  p.cant_variabila AS cant_variabila,
  p.nou            AS nou,
  p.congelat       AS congelat,
  p.cod            AS cod,
  p.poza           AS poza,
  cc.seo           AS seo
FROM produse p
  LEFT JOIN comenzi   c  ON p.id = c.produs
  LEFT JOIN cosuri    cs ON c.cos = cs.id
  LEFT JOIN categorii cc ON p.categorie = cc.id
WHERE cs.status = 'closed' AND p.vizibil = '1'
GROUP BY pid
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 0, 14
```

Of course it helps if there is an index for the following fields:

- p.id   (Primary keys are already indexed and won't need to create a new one)
- cc.id  (Primary keys are already indexed and won't need to create a new one)
- cs.id  (Primary keys are already indexed and won't need to create a new one)
- p.categorie
- p.vizibil (smaller potential gains here)
- c.produs
- c.cos
- cs.status (smaller potential gains here)
- p.pid (typical error to forget that group by needs to order records)